# deeplink sends incomplete serialized argument while using navigation component

Tags: android, gson, deep-linking, android-architecture-navigation, android-deep-link

I want to open a fragment using navigation component and deeplink.

```
val serializedUser = Gson().toJson(user)
findNavController().navigate(Uri.parse("myapp://?user=${serializedUser}"))
```

but in destination fragment sometimes argument is not complete.

```
val serializedUser = arguments?.getString("user")
val post = Gson().fromJson(serializedUser, User::class.java)
```

and getting this error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated string at line 1 column 1156 path $.text
```

if I log `serializedUser` in destination fragment this not complete and some character in end of it is not exist, while in first fragment it is complete.

serialized model is a long string but seems length of it is not related for this problem. because some longer serialized model working.

this problem is occur only if using navigation component deeplink.

Comment: The problem might be that `serializedUser` is not URL encoded before it is parsed; could you try using [`Uri.fromParts(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri#fromParts(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) or [`Uri.Builder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.Builder) instead?

Comment: thank you @Marcono1234. you did great help to me. please write your comment in answer so that I can vote and mark it as accept and other can see your answer better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Uri.parse(String)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri#parse(java.lang.String)) parses an encoded URI string, however you are not encoding `serializedUser`.

To solve this you should use [`Uri.fromParts(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri#fromParts(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) or the [`Uri.Builder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.Builder) class instead which does not require you to encode `serializedUser`.